# connect windows7 computer to windows10 computer via bluetooth

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I've checked the discoverable checkbox on both computers, found the other computer on add a device and got some number (to enter on the other computer, according to all websites I've found)

Where do I enter that number?

after a few seconds it disconnects with an authentication error and claims that the documentation of the device has more information, which is consistent with the websites I’ve found, but not terribly helpful.

Interestingly, it does keep the connection to my Ubuntu-computer, doesn't show a number but claims to have successfully added the device, be looking for drivers now and does show that computer in "devices and printers"

Comment: The other computer might ask for a PIN, which is most likely what that number that you mentioned is (if it's 4 digits long).

Comment: it's 6 digits long and asks "does the code match that device's code?" [Yes][No][The device does not show a code] (rough translation)

Comment: it disconnects no matter which checkbox i check